# Как заполнить ComboBox данными из ListBox(он заполняется по введённым данным в TextBox)?

Tags: c#, wpf

ListBox и ComboBox находятся в разных окнах.

Comment: тут главное - вопрос архитектуры: видимо данные при вводе из текстбокса лучше заполнять в какое то общее хранилище: доступное и для листбокса и для комбобокса

Comment: Model-View-ViewModel

Comment: Сделала элементы общедоступными. Также написала:`foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows){if (window.GetType() == typeof(Window5)){(window as Window5).СписокКлиентов = lstКлиенты;}}`
Но теперь не получается преобразовать ListBox в ComboBox.

Comment: Поймите что такое WPF, а не слепо делайте фиг пойми что. WPF, это XAML и Binding, вот два ваших инструментария, на которых должен базироваться весь проект. Если вы их не используете, вы страдаете, ваш проект страдает, получает уйму костылей, получает падения в производительности. Познайте азы, научитесь делать элементарные вещи! Вот вы хотите заполнить два контрола одинаковыми объектами, значит должен быть класс, который содержаит в себе публичное свойство коллекции, далее этот класс должен быть задан как `DataContext` окна, ну а в XAML просто `<... ItemsSource = "{Binding MyList}"/>`. Сложно?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, может и не сложно было бы, если бы также объясняли, как вы. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @s2f8 Ну так это в ваших интересах ведь, найти информацию, которая нужна вам. Есть документация от Microsoft, есть тот же Metanit, который имеет кучу полезного по C# и WPF, да даже тут, на SO, можете посмотреть мои ответы, ответы других участников, посмотреть, как там все устроено. Информации ведь полно и уже сотню раз решалось подобное, что вы просите. Ну вы ведь не ищите, вы сразу пошли задавать вопросы, причем максимально низкого качества, ну ведь не делается так. Помните, WPF это весьма простая технология, просто поймите как она устроена, научитесь делать привязки и познайте XAML.